# Windows Deployment Services Windows machines don't join automatically DNS wrong ip

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, wds

At my work we swapped out servers and starting from scratch. Previously had WDS on the old server and would join computers automatically to domain and push the correct DNS values on the client machines.
Now I am noticing the new server will install the image but when it first boots after a fresh install, it is not automatically connected to the domain. I checked the DNS values and they are not pointing to the domain controller. When I change dns values to domain controller and I can join domain manually and upon restart everything works as it supposed to.

I must have missed a step to make the clients get installed with the correct DNS values that point to the DC. Where do the clients get the DNS ip numbers from at first install?

Server 2012r2

roles installed

AD DS,
DNS,
WDS

DHCP is handled by the router.

Comment: They should be getting their DNS server assignments from DHCP. Have you checked the DNS servers that are being assigned by DHCP on the router?

Comment: I just checked the DNS on the router, it was due to the router thank you for this. I knew it was something simple I was overlooking.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WDS clients should be getting their DNS server assignments from DHCP. Check that the DNS servers that are being assigned by DHCP from the router are correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different modules that can handle DNS settings,

1. `DHCP` (automatic settings)
2. `Unattend.xml` (manual settings)

I am guessing that you don't want guest devices to use your MS ADDS DNS server so the best way to do that is having the ADDS joined computers use the MS DNS server by specifying in the `unattend.xml` file the DNS settings.

You can do this by going to the DNS Client settings in the Windows System Image manager and adding the settings to `unattend.xml`.

Or if you prefer the easy route add the DNS settings to the DHCP server as `@joeqwerty` said. I would not recommend that if it is on a public network or one that is not secured in a way that only authenticated/allowed devices can access.